# Replace Accent character with basic in a String - ą -> a , ć -> c

Tags: swift, string, special-characters, uisearchcontroller, diacritics

I'm removing accent characters from the Polish Alphabet when searching through a database. That way the user can type in text without accent.

I'm using this in my TableView search controller with approx 15,000 Strings. The code works but it is very slow, app freezes for a second with every letter typed.

Does anyone have a solution for more efficient approach?

My Filter for the TableView:

```
//My old method which didn't convert accent letters and works smoothly
var arr = dataSetArray.filter({$0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})

//My new filtering method
var arr = dataSetArray.filter({$0.forSorting().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
```

My Extension:

```
extension String {
func forSorting() -> String {
    let set = [("ą", "a"), ("ć", "c"), ("ę", "e"), ("ł", "l"), ("ń", "n"), ("ó", "o"), ("ś", "s"), ("ź", "z"), ("ż", "z")]
    let ab = self.lowercased()
    let new = ab.folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: nil)
    let final = new.replaceCharacters(characters: set)
    return final
    }
}

extension String {
    func replaceCharacters(characters: [(String, String)]) -> String
    {
        var input: String = self
        let count = characters.count
        if count >= 1
        {
            for i in 1...count
            {
                let c = i - 1
                let first = input
                let working = first.replacingOccurrences(of: characters[c].0, with: characters[c].1)
                input = working
            }
        }
        return input
    }
}
```

Comment: You are working much harder than you have to. The `.folding` call already eliminates all the diacritics you've listed, except for the polish ell. So you have only one character left that you need to substitute for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `range(of` with `caseInsensitive` and `diacriticInsensitive` options

```
let arr = dataSetArray.filter{ $0.localizedStandardRange(of: searchText) != nil }
```

without the extensions

Comment: Thanks, works nicely for most characters. Anything I can do about the Polish "ł", as that is not included in the above.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the hint, there is also an equivalent for `range(of`

Answer (score 1):

You can use localizedStandardContains which returns a Boolean value indicating whether the string contains the given string, taking the current locale into account.

Declaration

```
func localizedStandardContains<T>(_ string: T) -> Bool where T : StringProtocol
```

> Discussion
> This is the most appropriate method for doing user-level string searches, similar to how searches are done generally in the system.
> The search is locale-aware, case and diacritic insensitive. The exact
> list of search options applied may change over time

```
extension Collection where Element: StringProtocol {
    public func localizedStandardFilter(_ element: Element) -> [Element] {
        filter { $0.localizedStandardContains(element) }
    }
}
```

---

```
let array = ["cafe","Café Quente","CAFÉ","Coffe"]
let filtered = array.localizedStandardFilter("cafe")

filtered  // ["cafe", "Café Quente", "CAFÉ"]
```